# I'm trying to get a random order of numbers 1:16 using srand and rand. The code works as expected but only up to the 12th iteration.Why?

Tags: c++, find, srand

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;   

    int ord[] = {
             0,0,0,0,
             0,0,0,0,
             0,0,0,0
            };

    srand(time(NULL));

    int i = 0;

    do{
        int r = rand() % 16 + 1;
        bool exista =( find(begin(ord), end(ord), r) != end(ord));
        if (!exista){
            ord[i] = r;
            cout << ord[i] << endl;
            i++;
            cin.get();
        }

    } while (find(begin(ord), end(ord), 0) != end(ord));
    return 0;
}
```

After 12 numbers ,the program exits and I cannot understand why ,it should be after 16 iterations                                                                    .

Comment: Issues in C are not the same as in C++. Also solutions are (probably very) different for the 2 languages. C tag removed.

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Comment: Why should it end after 16 iterations? As far as I understand your code, you are rolling a dice until you get a number that you didnt get before. You keep track of this numbers in an array. This array has space for 12 numbers, so after you found 12 different numbers the program will exit.

Comment: Count the number of initialisers for `ord`, which determines the array size and hence the number of values generated. The answer should be obvious.

Comment: and btw.. if your program produces different result than what you expect, you should explain what and why you expect something different. Without any further explanation from your side there is not a single obvious reason why this should run for 16 iterations. (dont feel offended, just trying to give a hint how to ask better questions)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have only 12 zeros in `ord` and when they're exhausted (in your case filled with unique values from 1 to 16 the loop stops (because there are no more zeros to find.

changing the declaration of `ord` to

```
int ord[] = {
         0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0
        };
```

or

```
int ord[16] = {0};
```

By the way if you only want to shuffle those numbers randomly I'd suggest to use [`random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) from `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

You defined an array size of 12 and you are filling the array `ord[]` with the randomized integers `r`. Even though you set the random num generator to run for 16 iterations, your array will be filled on the twelfth iteration. Just increase your array size.